# How can I open a recent Pages file when I get the message "The required index.xml file is missing"

Tags: macos

How can I open a recent "Pages" file when I get the message "The required index.xml file is missing".
Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you maybe have 2 versions of Pages installed? Pages 5.2 is in your Applications folder and the Pages '09/'08 is in your Applications/iWork folder.

Answer (score 1):

Just right click on the pages file you want to open, and it will give you the option to "open with" the new version of pages.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to open the file after receiving that message by going into Applications/Pages/File/Open recent.  If the file is there I find I can open it.